# Can you trade in gen 4 games without touchscreen

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

I plan on purchasing pokemon HeartGold and platinum, I have a DS with a cracked screen and another one that’s perfectly fine, I have the gen 5 games, and those require touchscreen, is this required for gen 4 too?

Answer (score 1):

The Generation 4 games do not require the touchscreen to trade.